# Navigate a View(Login) in ContentRegion(Prism) at App.xaml.cs or on application Launch

Tags: prism, uno-platform

I am trying to navigate a login view in Prism ContentRegion on the launch of the application.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Login>("Login");
    }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        var regionManager = Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "Login");

    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do ? I'm not seeing the question.

Comment: I am trying to navigate a View(Login Use Control) in Prism ContentRegion(Shell.xaml). But it is not showing in the shell when shell.xaml gets loaded.

Comment: If you look at the properties of the region manager in a debugger before the RequestNavigate call is made, is your region listed in the currently available regions.  I had a similar problem documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577082/prism-6-region-manager-requestnavigate-fails-to-navigate-for-some-regions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related [to this issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2102) in PrismLib, where the navigation cannot yet be done directly from the OnInitialized.

As a workaround, you may do two thing, until this is fixed:

- Use RegisterViewWithRegion
- Or navigate only once the `Window` has been activated:

```
void Navigate(object sender, object args)
{
    regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "Login");

    Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Activated -= Navigate;
}

Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Activated += Navigate;
```